# Why kafka consumer code is not returning anything

Tags: php, windows, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka. I am using it in Windows 10. I have php 7.4. I have used  [arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka)  as php kafka client.

I downloaded Kafka from [here](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) and kept in c drive. Firstly, I tried producer and consumer on the command line using the following commands

```
Terminal 1: start zookeeper server
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

Terminal 2: start kafka
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Terminal 3: Create topic
.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic TestTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

List topics
.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Terminal 4: add data in topics
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic
press enter and now you can enter messages here

Terminal 5: consumer
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic --from-beginning
```

Everything is working fine till here. But my actual requirement is to consume data via PHP code so I can save data in the database. Now I am using command line producer that I discussed above and using the following PHP code for consumer, but it is not returning anything. Even I tried to produce data from [this](https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.examples-producer.html) code, but it is not producing data.

```
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('group.id', 'myConsumerGroup');
$rk = new RdKafka\Consumer($conf);
$rk->addBrokers("127.0.0.1");
$topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();
$topicConf->set('auto.commit.interval.ms', 100);
$topicConf->set('offset.store.method', 'broker');
$topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'earliest');
$topic = $rk->newTopic("TestTopic", $topicConf);
$topic->consumeStart(0, RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED);
while (true) {
    $message = $topic->consume(0, 2*10000);
    switch ($message->err) {
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
            var_dump($message);
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
            echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
            echo "Timed out\n";
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception($message->errstr(), $message->err);
            break;
    }
}
```

I am not getting, where is the mistake and what could be its fix?

Answer (score 0):

I assume PHP is also running on Windows. Did you check if php-rdkafka is being loaded by PHP?

You can try to add this to increase rdkafka debug messages

```
$conf->set('log_level', (string) LOG_DEBUG);
$conf->set('debug', 'all');
```